Dynamic Delegate Registration with Async Delegate
I followed the instructions for creating a dynamic delegate registration and it works fine.
My UDFs, however, need to run asynchronously so I tried a delegate with this signature:
Func<int, string, <Task<string>>. When excel loads, I get the error:
Registration [Error] Method not registered due to unsupported signature: 'Func`3.Invoke' : DnaMarshalException - Unknown Data Type: System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]
I half expected it not to work. Does anyone have an idea of how to create a dynamically registered async delegate?
Thanks.

I think you want to just fire off asynchronous code from a normal delegate, then get back on the main Excel thread from there if you need to.

I think I could easily get back on the main Excel UI thread but how would I be able to populate the cells needed?
What I found that works is using ExcelAsyncUtil.RunTask(). So far, this seems to do the trick.
